Crashing almost everytime when logging in or after suspend
Ubuntu 24.04, Asus Zenbook 13.
Since I updated to 24.04, the suspend function doesn't work well, almost each time I try to log back to my system, there is few seconds of nothing and then one of the following happens:

Sometimes just a black screen, I can move the touchpad cursor but nothing else happens (I must hard-reboot and hope for something good)
Sometimes Logging screen appears as intented, I can type my password and enter my session, but after a few seconds, the black screen happens and nothing works, then I must hard-reboot (sometimes it reboots itself...).
Sometimes it reboots instead of printing the logging screen, and after 2 or 3 attemps, I'm back to my Gnome session, BUT my few Gnome extension are all off (when I activate it again, it works ok)
Sometimes everything works ok at the first try, but this tends to happen less and less...

Few times a day I'm forced to hard-reboot (long press on the Power button for at least 8 seconds). I noticed that sometimes, when my computer is on suspend, it tends to become hot... like it's warming up slowly (far more than when I'm actually using it). Doesn't happen EVERY time I go to suspend, but tends to happen more and more.
Using gdm3 on my Gnome session.
Host: ZenBook UX325EA_UX325EA 1.0 
Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic 
Packages: 3081 (dpkg), 49 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.21 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 46.0 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-magenta-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru-magenta [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-1135G7 (8) @ 4.200GHz 
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] 
Memory: 3586MiB / 15688MiB

And here are the last lines of the command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockContainer [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashToDock] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashSlideContainer] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockBox [StBoxLayout] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor bms-dash-backgroundgroup [MetaBackgroundGroup] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor bms-dash-blurred-widget [StWidget] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockContainer [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashToDock] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashSlideContainer] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockBox [StBoxLayout] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor bms-dash-backgroundgroup [MetaBackgroundGroup] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor bms-dash-blurred-widget [StWidget] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockContainer [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashToDock] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashSlideContainer] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockBox [StBoxLayout] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor bms-dash-backgroundgroup [MetaBackgroundGroup] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor bms-dash-blurred-widget [StWidget] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockContainer [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashToDock] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashSlideContainer] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockBox [StBoxLayout] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor bms-dash-backgroundgroup [MetaBackgroundGroup] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor bms-dash-blurred-widget [StWidget] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockContainer [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashToDock] is on because it needs an allocation.
mai 16 15:59:15 Greguti-Asus gnome-shell[3753]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_docking_DashSlideContainer] is on because it needs an allocation.


Since yesterday, the problem seems to disappear after I changed one thing to my congif: I got rid of RClone to connect to my distant servers (kDrive with WebDAV and Onedrive), because Gnome 46 allows for these connections from the Parameters app. For now the suspend/logging back process is ok...
